# Python argparse boolean issue

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I am having trouble setting a boolean value. My code is:

```
training_pages_list_file = ''
html_page_dir = ''
clf_file_str = ''
user_idf_param = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Classify some CraigsList Pages')
    parser.add_argument('csv_file', action='store')
    parser.add_argument('file_dir', action='store')
    parser.add_argument('clf_file', action='store')
    parser.add_argument('-i', action='store_true', help="include idf", dest=user_idf_param, default=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

However, this raises:

```
hon3.4/argparse.py", line 1721, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/argparse.py", line 1742, in parse_known_args
    if not hasattr(namespace, action.dest):
TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string
```

How can I have it so if `-i` is included, it will set `user_idf_param` to `True`?

Comment: `argparse` does not set the values of global variables.  It sets attributes of the `args` object that `parse_args` returns.

Comment: http://argparse4j.sourceforge.net/index.html  is a Java library modeled on `argparse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `user_idf_param` is supposed to be a name for the attribute that tells you whether or not it was used.

```
import argparse

training_pages_list_file = ''
html_page_dir = ''
clf_file_str = ''
user_idf_param = "i_param_used"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Classify some CraigsList Pages')
    parser.add_argument('csv_file', action='store')
    parser.add_argument('file_dir', action='store')
    parser.add_argument('clf_file', action='store')
    parser.add_argument('-i', action='store_true', help="include idf", dest=user_idf_param, default=False)

    args = parser.parse_args((...))

    if args.i_param_used:
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you! That is not at all what I was expecting. The documentation is really bad for this module

Comment: The `argparse` authors probably assumed that users were already familiar with older parsers like `optparse` and `get_opt`, and glossed over issues that could confuse Python beginners.